# Show that the running time of the build_heap function is $O(n)$

Tags: algorithms

I'm not entirely sure whether this question fits on math.stackexchange, but since it's basically a question about asymptotic running time, I thought I'd try to post it here. In case it's not appropriate, please delete this question.

Given the following two functions, prove that the build_heap function, which transforms an array A into a max-heap-sorted array A' runs in $O(n)$.

heapify(A, i):

```
Input: array A of length n, index i

left = 2i + 1 (left child node) 
right = 2i + 2 (right child node) 
largest = i if left < n and A[left] > A[i] then     
    largest = left 
end if 
if right < n and A[right] > A[largest] then     
    largest = right end 
if if largest != i then     
    swap(A, i, largest)     
    heapify(A, largest) 
end if
```

build_heap(A):

```
Input: Array of length n

for i = floor((n-1)/2) to 0 do
    heapify(A, i)
end for
```

Hint: Assume that A has $2^j-1$, for $j \in \mathbb{N}$, elements. You can also use the fact that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k}{2^k} = 2$.

I don't really understand why the formula is given in the hint, or rather how to explicitly use it to prove that build_heap(A) runs in $O(n)$.

I would say that the worst case for the heapify function is given when a call of heapify(A,0) calls itself recursively as much as possible. I think a binary tree with n nodes has depth of $\lceil lg(n) \rceil $, so the maximum number of recursive calls should be $\lceil lg(n) \rceil $.

I'm not sure but my guess is that the formula is trying to tell me that the running time of heapify is $O(1)$?! But I don't really see how that's possible. If it were a constant then clearly build_heap(A) would run in $O(n)$, but how can it be constant?

Can someone please help me out?